# Add hidden field in a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

have a custom html form in page:

```
    <form action="localhost/mail.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="USERNAME_HERE" /></li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit">Send request</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

Can I somehow add current logged username name in to value=... ?
So when user will click "Send request" button, I will receive his username in email?

Tried use [userinfo field="user_login"] and :

```
    <?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";

?>
```

But all php code was cut so it is useless :(

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: where are you adding the php code?

Comment: Hi All and thank you for reply, probably i was not clear in the topic.
Is here any way to add username in Dashboard -> Pages -> HTML page ?
Not in template pages.
THanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I use page templates to work with PHP in pages. Once you have your template set up you can do something like this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom Form
 * Description: Form with pre-filled username. 
 */

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
?>

 <form action="localhost/mail.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
 <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="submit">Send request</button>
    </li>
</ul>

</form>
```

You'll probably want to copy page.php from your theme into a file called page-form.php for your template, then modify page-form.php. Look for the_content(); and add your custom PHP there.

You can read more about templates here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: Can I add this code in to Dashboard->Pages-HTML? No :( All php code removed after I save the page...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't natively use PHP in posts or pages. I know this might seem like a lot of work but it's very useful to know how to create templates while working with WordPress and I promise you won't regret learning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
<?php

$user_nameField = $_POST['user_name'];



?>





    <form action="localhost/mail.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
        <input  name="user_name" type="hidden"  id="user_name"  value="<?php echo $ulog; ?>"></li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit">Send request</button>
            </li>
        </ul>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/

You will need to create a block of php code in this plugin then put it in your page as short code.

so your php code will look like this:

```
<?php 
      global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      $username = $current_user->user_login;

?>
<form action="localhost/mail.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit">Send request</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>
```